# How to make another app open in Game Maker?

Tags: execute, game-maker

I'm using Game Maker for Mac by YoYo Games, and I was wondering if it's possible to open another app in a Game Maker game by pressing a button. Sorry if this doesn't seem very clear, tell me if it isn't.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I do not know about the mac-version, but in the windows-version it can be done using the following functions:

**execute_program(prog,arg,wait)**

**execute_shell(prog,arg)**

Answer (score 1):

`execute_program`, `execute_shell` and `execute_file` are obsolete. Don't use them, they will be removed.

Why?

> These functions cannot be used any more due to changes in the underlying runner that GameMaker:Studio uses to generate the device specific packages making it impossible to generate objects, images or code "on the fly" as was done before.

How to fix this? I'd make a DLL for Windows and some other DLL-like program (I guess .vst or .so? ) for the Mac version, that can run external codes